# How to share UserData between EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

To configure a set EC2 instances, i plan to define the UserData property for each instance.

If i do that,i will write for each one commands like

- apt-get update -y
- apt-get upgrade -y
- and so on

I wonder how to share some parts of a UserData content between several instances to avoid to repeat script lines.

I found two solutions :

1. Define a mapping variable with one value par line to repeat
2. Define a AWS::CloudFormation::Init section for one instance and using it to others instances with cfn-init -v --resource "myResourceToShareUserData"

The first option is burdensome  and the second uses a part of an instance for a purpose which is not the primary goal.

Is there others tips ?

Best regards

Comment: It seems like you're asking how to do that in the Context of a CloudFormation template, correct?

Comment: Indeed @Maurice, apologize i forgot this point.

Answer (score 0):

I'd place all common code on an S3 bucket as a script and then I'd pull that in in the UserData:

```bash
...
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/myscript.sh .
chmod +x ./myscript.sh
./myscript.sh
...
```

Comment: That seems smart, and I should be able to create S3 bucket in my CloudFormation template :). I will try to use your suggestion.

Comment: @nizery well no, if you use this solution the S3 bucket would have to exist outside of this template. alternatively you could place it publicly somewhere like GitHub, however then the EC2 instances would have to have internet connectivity

Comment: Why should the bucket exist outside the template ? It is not possible to create a bucket in a template, and the use it using the DependsOn attribute ?

Comment: @nizery how would you upload the script to the bucket?

Comment: ah ok if you say that it means that's not possible with CloudFormation to define the content of a bucket. Ok

Comment: @nizery if my answer worked for you, then consider accepting it/upvoting it

Comment: I would like to test it before ... But i will vote don't worry

Comment: @nizery sure, let me know how you get on